# Need to play video in videoview only by buffering it without downloading full video at first. Is there any library for this?

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, android-videoview

I have a project dealing with playing videos in videoview. Video is playing good and no problem in it. Problem is that the video is loading in videoview after getting downloaded fully. So it take a initial time to start the video. Its a big problem for me and I need a solution or any library suitable for buffer the video url (for 20%) and play without loading completely.

```
    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(
            new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

                    progress_bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    if (mCurrentPosition > 0) {
                        videoView.seekTo(mCurrentPosition);
                    } else {
                        videoView.seekTo(1);
                    }
                    videoView.start();
                }
            });
```

Comment: I have same issue . I have searched a lot but I didn't get a solution. Is there any library for this.

Comment: Go for ExoPlayer then. You can do lot more things using exoplayer.

Comment: Exoplayer have this feature ? Is Exoplayer customized for buffer video without fully downloading ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, ExoPlayer is generally a good idea for video playback on Android so it would be worth considering using it.

For your particular issue, however, you probably want to look at the server side, in particular to ensure your server accepts range requests and to ensure the video is set up for fast start if it is an MP4 - this moves the metadata information to the start of the video rather than the end.

You can find some more info on range requests here, along with an example of how to check if the server accepts them: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests

```js
curl -I http://i.imgur.com/z4d4kWk.jpg

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 146515
```

Most servers do accept them so if you find it does not it may be just a configuration issue.

For moving the mp4 'MooV atom', the metadata header info, to the start there are quite a few tools which will allow you do this including the open source handbrake tool (look at the 'web optimised' tick box):

- https://handbrake.fr

Comment: So its all belong to server side. On frondend we don't have any work or support ?

Comment: Nearly all video players will support this now, including HTML5 video tags etc, both for live streams and for Video On Demand